# What are the correct steps to prepare and publish a Typescript/ES6 React-Native component as an npm package?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, webpack, babeljs

I have a very simple `react-native` component that I want to publish to `npm` so other apps can use it, the following is `src/index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class MyText extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{'Hello'}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default MyText;
```

I want my code to be written in Typescript. I will use `webpack` to transpile the code first from `Typescript` to `ES6`, then from `ES6` to `ES5`.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@myproject/mycomponent",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.3.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.3.3",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.38",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.51.1",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-native": "^0.58.4"
  },
  "files": [
    "build/**/*"
  ]
}
```

And `babel.rc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/react", "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/typescript", "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"
  ]
}
```

And `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|build)/,
        use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
};
```

When I run `yarn install` then `yarn run build`, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/classCallCheck' in '/Users/evian/projects/mycomponent/src'
 @ ./src/index.tsx 1:207-255

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/createClass' in '/Users/evian/projects/mycomponent/src'
 @ ./src/index.tsx 1:298-343

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/getPrototypeOf' in '/Users/evian/projects/mycomponent/src'
 @ ./src/index.tsx 1:505-553

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/inherits' in '/Users/evian/projects/mycomponent/src'
 @ ./src/index.tsx 1:593-635

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault' in '/Users/evian/projects/mycomponent/src'
 @ ./src/index.tsx 1:27-82

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/possibleConstructorReturn' in '/Users/evian/projects/mycomponent/src'
 @ ./src/index.tsx 1:400-459

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/evian/projects/mycomponent/src'
 @ ./src/index.tsx 1:671-687

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native' in '/Users/evian/projects/mycomponent/src'
 @ ./src/index.tsx 1:706-729
```

Why do I get these errors?
If I then `yarn add react react-native` (that is, I actually install these libraries in my project and don't have them simply as peer dependencies), and `yarn run build` again, I get tons of errors of the following type:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'AccessibilityInfo' in '/Users/evian/projects/mycomponent/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native'
 @ ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js 23:11-39
 @ ./src/index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ActionSheetIOS' in '/Users/evian/projects/mycomponent/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native'
 @ ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js 188:11-36
 @ ./src/index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ActivityIndicator' in '/Users/evian/projects/mycomponent/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native'
 @ ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js 26:11-39
 @ ./src/index.tsx
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: First thing I realized is I should add `externals` to my `webpack.config.js`, adding react and react-native keys. However, this does not solve the babel helpers issue. I realize that the babel stuff is transient, ie, it's just an error likely related to versioning of dependencies. But I'd like to know what are the general steps in publishing a RN component, that is the focal point of this question.

Comment: here is my config from my personal typescript/react project that compiles into a commonjs package to be imported 
https://pastebin.com/mfvsMmm3